# Series and Summations .Finding sum of infinite series.

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have tried to solve this question and have made several attempts using Series Reversal, Method of Differences and approximation after the smaller values. However due to the exponents of the denominators  it is tough to conclude.Can somebody please help me out??.
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k^3(k+1)^3} = S
$$
Find value of S

Comment: Can you tail us if it is finite ($n<\infty$) or infinite($n\to \infty$) series we are dealing with?

Comment: I would suggest by doing a partial fraction decomposition on the summand.

Comment: According to Mathematica the partial sum up to $n$ has a really ugly form. However the series for $n \to \infty$ has a much nicer result.

Comment: As @Tucker suggested, the "obvious" (not necessarily the simplest nor fastest) first attempt would be to write $$\frac{1}{k^3(k+1)^3} = \frac{1}{k^3}-\frac{1}{(k+1)^3}-3\left(\frac{1}{k^2}+\frac{1}{(k+1)^2}\right)+6\left(\frac{1}{k}-\frac{1}{k+1}\right)$$
and deal with the partial sums separately.

Comment: The result for n$\to\infty$ is here: http://www.bitman.name/math/article/84/115

Comment: It is an Infinite series

Comment: @AurojeetJena You should have either $\sum_{k=1}^\infty$ or $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n$) in that case. Most of the comments above are still valid, as they implicitly assumed you meant that.

Comment: The result follows immediately from @ClementC.'s answer, using $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac1{k^2}=\frac{\pi^2}6$.

Comment: @Zubzub. The result for the partial sum is not so ugly .... provided that you know about the polygamma functions. Cheers.

Comment: Can someone please solve it for me? It would be of great help.

Comment: @AurojeetJena With the above, you have everything you need to at least **try** to solve your question.

Comment: OK I will try. Thank you everybody cared to help me out.